# Suppress Coloring in VIM

Tags: vim

I am using the VIM editor for my projects. It's a fine editor but one thing bugs me, namely coloring of text, see example below:
[image]

I've tried various ways to suppress this with no luck, e.g. in the .vimrc and using :se commands.

**Is this even possible?**

Comment: [`:syntax off`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/syntax.html) ?

Comment: I tried that but got the error "can't open file <dir>/syntax/nosyntax.vim" where <dir> is the directory of vim.exe.

Comment: Seems like a broken installation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my problem. I had copied VIM.EXE to another directory (without its subdirectories) and was executing it from there. So it couldn't find its *.vim files. When I executed it from the original location, all was good.

Answer (score 0):

[image: colors off, bold on]

That is how Vim should look like with the following `~/.vimrc`:

```
let &t_Co=1
syntax on
```

Note that my Terminal emulator is set to use a bold font for bold colors. With that setting disabled, it looks like this:

[image: colors off, bold off]

You still get some styling (reverse, underline, etc.) but the result is quite soothing.

`:help t_Co` determines how much colors Vim has at its disposal for syntax highlighting. A value of `256` tells it that it can use [the whole xterm palette](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/15/Xterm_256color_chart.svg), a value of `16` tells it to restrain itself to the 16 colors at the bottom of the chart, and a value of `1` essentially tells it to not use colors at all, and other values are possible.